# Laravel 5: View Composer and Service Provider not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, service-provider

I want to show some data from database in multiple views. I am using View Composer and Service provider for this purposes but it is not working.

This is my app/Http/ViewComposers/CategorycountComposer.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\View\View;

use DB;

use App\General_model;

class CategorycountComposer
{
    public $categoriescount = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $query = "SELECT ct.`category_title`,ct.`category_id`,(SELECT COUNT(`job_id`) FROM `job_details` WHERE `category_id` = ct.`category_id`) AS totall FROM `job_category` AS ct ORDER BY ct.`category_title` ASC";
        $this->categoriescount = General_model::rawQuery($query);
    }


    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('categoryCount',$this->categoriescount);
    }
}
```

This is my app/Providers/CategorycountServiceProvider.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CategorycountServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
         view()->composer(
            ['layouts.category_panel','jobs.jobdetails'],
            'App\Http\ViewComposers\CategorycountComposer'
        );
    }


    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

This is m config/app.php file

```
  'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\CategorycountServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */
        Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    ],
```

This is my layouts.category_panel.blade.php file

```
<ul class="list-group" style="border: none">
<li class="list-group-item" style="background-color:#f2f2f2"><strong>Search by Category</strong></li>
@foreach($categoryCount as $category) 
<li class="list-group-item">{{$category->category_title}} 
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">{{$category->totall</span> 
</li> 
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Now every time I try to open the view, it gives me the following error

> Undefined variable: categoryCount (View:
>   C:\AppServ\www\getajob\project\resources\views\layouts\categ‌​ory_panel.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\AppServ\www\getajob\project\resources\views\layouts\categ‌​ory_panel.blade.php)

Comment: you're overwriting categoryCount in your for each

Comment: I did not get you. How am I overwriting foreach??

Comment: Use it like this `@foreach($categoryCount as $category)
<li class="list-group-item">{{$category->category_title}}
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">{{$category->totall</span>
</li>
@endforeach`

Comment: it still gives me the same error: Undefined variable: categoryCount (View: C:\AppServ\www\getajob\project\resources\views\layouts\category_panel.blade.php) (View: C:\AppServ\www\getajob\project\resources\views\layouts\category_panel.blade.php)

Answer (score -1):

You should use `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: You should provide explanation. Why use this line ? Why the OP solution is not working ?